# how to put html body on mailto href with lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforce-for-outlook, lightning-for-outlook

I have created quick action button to open outlook app,and behind the scene I Am using LWC Headless Action to make it happen.

following is my complete lwc code.

***TestSendEmail.html***

```
<template>
    
</template>
```

***TestSendEmail.js***

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TestSendEmail extends LightningElement {
    @api invoke() {    
        var uri = "mailto:?subject=Test%20subject"+"&body="+encodeURIComponent("<table><tr><td>Test Html</td></tr></table>");
        console.log("show uri: ", uri);

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = uri;
        a.click();        
    }
}
```

***TestSendEmail.js-meta.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>Action</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

And here's the button after added to page layout:
[image]
But when I click  the button, html does not get rendered properly on outlook app like this following image
[image]

The goal is only to open outlook app with correct rendered HTML. Hope anyone can help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. [RFC 2368](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2368) states:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
>
> body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
>
> the **first text/plain body** part of the message. ...

*(Emphasis added).*

In other words, HTML just isn't allowed in the body, or anywhere else, in the mailto protocol.

It goes on to say:

> ... The mailto URL is
>
> primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
>
> actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
>
> messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

Therefore, the rationale is that the mailto protocol is not suitable for composing complicated/encoded messages.